# Visual studio not attaching to debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, chromium

`Randomly my visual studio IIS Express stopped being able to attach. I think I have traced down the issue that chrome debugger is not communicating back with visual studio. Something is blocking it. When I launch my application with IIS Express, the chrome window comes up, but never connects to my localhost::port. And then I get this:

[image]

On another machine, when I launch my working IIS Express, and do a netstat command I get this.

[chrome.exe]

TCP    127.0.0.1:52047        LALFIACLT244584:9229   SYN_SENT        8560

My laptop that isn't working never gets that far. I have checked for firewall ports blocking and other things that I could think of and still cannot get it to attach. I have uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, edge, visual studio, IIS Express. Updated and downgraded versions, etc. Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: Did you check the output window?

Comment: Yes. Some logs in there is how I was able to track down the tcp port stuff.

Comment: You should post it